# How can I recognize Windows file paths in a string in Perl?

Tags: windows, regex, perl, path

I have been doing some searching for a regex that can be used as a rule to disallow users entering windows file paths without escaping the "\".  So far I have found this expression

> [^\\]*$

However, this fails for the following:

> C:\\Program Files\\testing

By fails I mean that it does not validate this string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and yes I am bound to using regex.

Comment: What language/regex engine are your using?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why don't you want your users to enter un-escaped Windows file paths?

Comment: this is from within the context of an install package, the underlying issue is when I pass this to a jar that utilizes the java Properties object the slashes get eaten.  This is not an issue with the use of Java File objects, however as things go there are constraints on both sides of the fence

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Hi brian it has to be regex because that's the constraint of the application where this resides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(\\\\|[^\\])*$
```

will match strings that only contain escaped `\` characters or non-`\` characters. (For a little extra performance, you could improve it to: `^(?:\\\\|[^\\]+)*$`)

In Perl:

```
if ($subject =~ m/^(?:\\\\|[^\\]+)*$/) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

This will match

```
C:\\Program Files\\test
abcd
h983475iuh 87435v z 87tr8v74
\\\\\\\\\\
```

and fail

```
C:\Program Files\test
\
\\\
```

etc.

Comment: this does not function accordingly on my system

Comment: If I pass "C:\Program Files\testing"  it accepts it, this is not what I am anticipating

Comment: Try passing 'C:\Program Files\testing' (using single quotes instead of double quotes). Inside double quotes, backslash is an escape character; inside single quotes it isn't.

Comment: thats what it was, windows makes me so sad.

Answer (score 2):

If you pulled this trick on me as a user of your application, I would be rather annoyed.  Why not instead of forcing the user to provide data in a certain format, you reformat the data after the user has entered it?

Take a look at the `quotemeta` function ([perldoc -f quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)), which will automatically escape all backslashes (and other potentially-special characters) for you.

Comment: Ill take a look into this, but most likely I won't have a very far least to work with.

Comment: +1: It should be the program's job to not create odd head scratching things for the user.

Comment: oh i agree whole heartedly drewk, but sometimes you have to rely on the vendor that supplies the tools you use.